# How can I disable XQuartz entirely and use Xorg with my own Desktop Environment?

Tags: macports, x11, xquartz

I want to use `i3`, which is available in Mac Ports. I've installed it and `xorg` (with `ports install xorg`). Now I want to boot into that. I've tried created an `~/.xinitrc` and an `~/.xinitrc.d/99_i3` script (both had `+x`). But in neither occasion did X start up with the script. Is it possible to use `Xorg` on boot and jump into `i3` instead of the normal OSX Window Manager?

You can find a very similar question on [SuperUser here](https://superuser.com/q/459273/11116).

Just to be clear, **I don't want any OSX functionality. I'm only not reformatting and installing GNU Linux because my company prohibits it. I want to bootstrap a parallel configuration with ports and boot into an i3 environment (ideally with no dock, Aqua, Finder).**

Comment: X quartz is x11 and not the usually osx windowing the latter is quartz. Also x quartz is the current version of x.org. What are you asking?

Comment: I've installed Xorg through macports, I want to use it instead of X quartz.

Comment: Macports installs x quartz not.org. https://www.macports.org/install.php What exactly have you done and which instructions have you used?

Comment: @Mark `port install i3` `port install xorg`

Comment: The super user question is how to run X11 programs on OSX.

Comment: Given your last sentace you can't. macOS/OSX includes dock, Aqua, Finder etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because thjis question is making incorrect assumptions about OSX also what the OP is asking for cannot be done.

Comment: Why don't you answer by clarifying the assumptions and saying it can not be done. I'm still not clear why.

Comment: You limited yourself with the restriction.  You could install Darwin then install any screen manager you want.   I don't think your company would like your solution.  You would have limited a bunch of tools they probably want to use for admin.

Comment: Why don't you just install all the tools you want and run from the terminal?

Comment: Well, I'm limited by something external -- but why does that matter. This still seems like it is openly on topic as it pertains to Apple Software, (the kernel), the removal or reworking of some Apple Software (the graphic stuff), and it's all done on Apple Hardware. https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic It just seems like a regular question from the perspective of a power user. For comparison, aside from Linux, Windows users have been doing this stuff since at least [Windows 98](http://toastytech.com/guis/l98.html).

Comment: Check out iterm2.  It's an advanced terminal app. https://www.iterm2.com/features.html  Split Panes

Divide a tab up into multiple panes, each one showing a different session. You can slice vertically and horizontally and create any number of panes in any imaginable arrangement.   It would let you do all the terminal sessions you want.  Don't know what would happen if you tried to run an x11 app in a pane.

Comment: Windows users have not been doing this since Windows 98 - Windows NT and on does not run a separate GUI on top of a OS it is all one. See how it runs services and most admin tools a GUI based. At least macOS can be run from command line

Comment: @history stamp iTerm is exactly like Terminal re X11.

Comment: You need to hack around. There may be a way of doing it. I suggest looking around the Darwin forum.  macOS calls the unix layer, Darwin.

Comment: @historystamp but to run Darwin you have to reinstall it and the OPs company will not allow that

Comment: You could get the free Oracle Virtual Box and run any linux distro you want in it.  I've run linux in VB.  Don't know how stable it might be.

Comment: Have you considered leaving macOS alone and just dual-booting into Linux? Doesn't require a reinstall and will probably be more stable than anything else you're trying... for example, https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733

Comment: @dr.nixon company forces you to Think Different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, what you actually want to do is to get rid of the Mac graphic environment, and run a "classic" X11 session instead. Correct?

I don't think you can get rid of the Mac graphic environment entirely (short of installing some other OS, like *BSD or Linux), but you can hide it to a certain extent.

Configure Xquartz to run in full-screen mode (it's in the settings somewhere...). This means you won't see any Mac stuff. Create an ~/.xinitrc file. Xquartz will run that file on start-up, just as would normally happen with startx or xinit. In that file, you can start any window manager you like. e.g. good old twm. (If you don't have an .xinitrc file, Quartz will start the quartz-wm window manager, which gives a "Mac look" to your X windows.) It should be theoretically possible to get an entire Gnome desktop running, but I have not tried that... You'll still have to boot into MacOS and log in to a Mac desktop, but after you have started Xquartz, you should be back in familiar X11 land.

(I get the impression that you believe Xquartz *is* the standard graphic Mac environment. It isn't. Xquartz is an X server that runs on top of the Mac graphic environment. I think Xquartz is just a packaging of the Xorg server, built for macOS, but I could be wrong on that.)

Comment: Is there any web browser built for X11?

Comment: Lynx? ;-) It seems there was a firefox-x11 package in Homebrew ages ago, but it was dropped for lack of maintenance. It should be theoretically possible to get Firefox or Chromium running on X11/macOS (after all, they run on X11/Linux which isn't all that different) but my guess is that you will have to compile it yourself...